# How to debug SQL Server Agent Jobs?

Tags: ssis

I two SSIS packages that both run fine on my local machine. I can import them to SSIS on the server and execute them both with no problems. However, I need to run them in series every night at 3AM. Thus, I created a SQL Server Agent Job with two steps. The first step runs the first package successfully. The second step should run the second package but it fails with this error message:

> Message
>       Executed as user: IT-DEV\itdev. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:27:21 PM 
>   Error: 2013-05-30 13:27:21.53     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Create
>   text files on IT DEV      Description: Exception has been thrown by
>   the target of an invocation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution
>   returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  1:27:21 PM  Finished: 1:27:21
>   PM  Elapsed:  0.375 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step
>   failed.

Both packages move some files from one directory to another and do some work. They both run in the same security context using the same proxy. I can see the work completed successfully from step 1, but again step 2 fails. I have looked through all possible step settings for each and see no differences. Thus, how can I get a more descriptive message so I know what the real issue is. I'm guessing its permissions but again both packages do similar work in similar locations requiring the same permissions. One runs, the other doesn't. Please help. Thanks in advance.

FYI I've also turned SSIS logging on and write everything to a file but the message below is the only error I see.

---

**UPDATE**

I ended up writing to a text file all over inside the script task to try to identify the problem. I seem to be getting stuck here:

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + myPath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=NO;FMT=TabDelimited\"";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MYFILE.txt", connStr);
outfile.WriteLine("Adapter Created");
DataTable dtFiles = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dtFiles);
outfile.WriteLine("Filled DataTable");
```

I never see "Filled DataTable" in the file I'm writing to... the last entry says "Adapter Created".

Comment: Most hits for this error message seem to describe variable typing issue in a script task.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820029/ssis-user-variable-assignment) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic743911-148-1.aspx).  The latter link also discusses setting up an OnError event handler for a Task in the Control Flow.  That might help you dig out more information about what is happening.

Comment: These are SQL Server 2012 packages, are they using the new project deployment model (and thus are in the SSISDB catalog) or are they still using the package deployment model and live in msdb?

Comment: They are live in msdb. However, I was able to write to a text file on the server and pinpoint what is causing the error. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to replace this: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 with this: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 because I'm running the agent job on Windows Server 2008 64 bit.